# replace fireplace switch with nest thermostat

Tags: electrical, thermostat

I have a fireplace wired up to a switch (simple off/on), and I want to throw a Nest thermostat on there.

It has a black and white wire coming out of the wall. I think the white goes to the W1 and the black goes to the RH?

I may have to run a common wire as well I read.

But is there any risk replacing the switch? Do I have my hook up correct?

Comment: how much current is seen by the switch?

Comment: 50mA through the switch

Comment: i'm just some dude on the internet, but it sounds like it should be fine. use a relay buffer if in doubt.

Comment: Most fireplaces are millivolt actuated, if you do not have power at the switch it may take quite a bit more as nest thermostats are not millivolt devices. More info will probably be needed. If the switch goes directly back to the gas relay is is probably millivolt running off a thermocouple, or thermopile in the pilot flame for the voltage to open the gas valve.

Comment: @EdBeal the leads do come from the thermopile. Is that bad or good?

Comment: Not bad I just think you will need a transformer to power the nest and a relay.

Comment: @EdBeal so can i plug the white cable into W1 and black into RH, and then run a common 24 AC to the C port? There is a plug nearby so I could put the transformer there.

Comment: @sci-guy -- you're forgetting about the *relay*

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought the Nest is essentially a giant relay? What would I need another for? Basically when those two wires are connected the fireplace turns on -- can't the nest do this ?

Comment: It has been a few years since I did this and both a relay and transformer were needed, yes the nest is an electronic controller but it uses solid state switches, not relay contacts. The solid state switches have a voltage drop where relay contacts do not. a millivolt valve won’t have enough power to open with any voltage drop that is why the relay is needed. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

### You need *both* a transformer *and* a relay to do this

The Nest cannot switch a millivolt system on its own, even when supplied with 24VAC, as it has solid-state output switches instead of mechanical relays.  Hence, you'll need both a 24VAC transformer *and* a 24VAC fan relay in order to control your fireplace from your Nest.  The transformer secondary goes to Rh and C, while the relay coil is connected to W and C, and the relay contacts connect to the existing switch wires.

Comment: Should have read your answer and upvoted prior to commenting, +